# _beginthreadex static member function

Tags: c++, function, static, multithreading, member

How do I create a thread routine of a static member function

```
class Blah
{
    static void WINAPI Start();
};

// .. 
// ...
// ....

hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, CBlah::Start, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
***error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void (void)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'***
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes, it is useful to read the error you're getting.

```
cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void (void)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'
```

Let's look at what it says. For parameter three, you give it a function with the signature `void(void)`, that is, a function which takes no arguments, and returns nothing. It fails to convert this to `unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)`, which is what `_beginthreadex` *expects*:

It expects a function which:

- Returns an `unsigned int`:
- Uses the `stdcall` calling convention
- Takes a `void*` argument.

So my suggestion would be "give it a function with the signature it's asking for".

```
class Blah
{
    static unsigned int __stdcall Start(void*);
};
```

Comment: thanks but im not familiar with func pointers : )

lemme try your solution

Comment: Then this might help you some:
The Function Pointer Tutorials - http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Answer (score 3):

```
class Blah
{
    static unsigned int __stdcall Start(void*); // void* should be here, because _beginthreadex requires it.
};
```

The routine passed to `_beginthreadex` must use the `__stdcall` calling convention and **must return a thread exit code**.

Implementation of Blah::Start:

```
unsigned int __stdcall Blah::Start(void*)
{
  // ... some code

  return 0; // some exit code. 0 will be OK.
}
```

Later in your code you could write any of the following:

```
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, CBlah::Start, NULL, NULL, NULL);
// or
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &CBlah::Start, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

In first case `Function-to-pointer conversion` will be applied according to C++ Standard 4.3/1. In second case you'll pass pointer to function implicitly.

Comment: Nice one!  Especially the function-to-pointer conversion I didn't know. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
class Blah
{
  public:
    static DWORD WINAPI Start(void * args);
};
```

Comment: missing the `void*` parameter that is part of the expected signature.

Comment: Thanks - the sad thing is that was copied (incorrectly) from working code - maybe I'm getting to old for this :-(

Comment: when you are anyway at it with windows defines, use LPVOID for arg :)

Answer (score 2):

Following is the compiling version:

```
class CBlah
{
public:
    static unsigned int WINAPI Start(void*)
    {
    return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &CBlah::Start, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Following are the changes required:

(1). Start() function should return unsigned int

(2). It should take a void* as the parameter.

**EDIT**

Deleted point (3) as per comment

Comment: For static function `Function-to-pointer conversion` will be applied. So no need in (3).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Blah
{
    static unsigned int __stdcall Start(void *);
};
```

Comment: Why unsigned int? I'm not returning any thing from the thread. Even if I had to return something what should I return

Comment: Same reason you have int main() : because your thread should return something, by design. Just return 0, if you have nothing better.

Comment: Not working


class Blah
{
    static unsigned int __stdcall Start();
};

unsigned int Blah::Start() {}

now this error

: error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'unsigned int (void)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'

Comment: WINAPI should do the trick.  When working with windows API, why not stick to their terminology?  You missed the obligatory void* function argument -1

Comment: @xtofl - thanks for the void* catch. I like to avoid using macros whenever it makes sense. In this case I could go either way.