# C++ Thread in member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, function

can I use thread in member function to call a member function for C++ in windows? If yes, how to implement it? Here is the sample

```
void Class::fun_1(void){
 _beginthread(fun_2, 0, NULL); //This is the error line :: function call missing argument list; use '&Class::fun_2' to create a pointer to member
}

void Class::fun_2(void){
 printf("hello");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, `_beginthread` is a function from the dark old world called `win32`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [_beginthreadex static member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259815/beginthreadex-static-member-function)

Comment: Any other provide Thread function in windows C++?? except _beginthread

Comment: @Ian: you should use the newer and safer `CreateThread` API, the old crt threading routines have many incompatabilities

Comment: @J-16 _beginthread is not part of win32

Comment: @Necrolis: Not if the thread itself calls C runtime functions. The last paragraph of the Remarks section: ["A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the `_beginthreadex` and `_endthreadex` functions for thread management..."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually multiple issues here:

1. You can't pass a pointer to a member function as the routine to the `_beginthread()` function. The function requires a pointer to a global or static function.
2. Standard C++ requires that you fully qualify the member function name (even within the class) and use an `&` to obtain a pointer to the member (the compiler was complaining to you about this point).

Because you can't pass a member function pointer to `_beginthread()`, you need to create a wrapper global or static function to make it work. Here's one way to make that happen:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void fun_1()
    {  
        _beginthread(&MyClass::fun_2_wrapper, 0, static_cast<void*>(this));
    }

private:
    void fun_2()
    {
        printf("hello");  
    }  

    static void __cdecl fun_2_wrapper(void* o)
    {
        static_cast<MyClass*>(o)->fun_2();
    }
};
```

Of course, you need to somehow guarantee that the `MyClass` object will still exist for as long as `fun_2()` is running, or not-so-good things will happen. If you much rather not have to worry about it, consider using [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread.html) which does basically this and much more for you.

Comment: If fun_2 will access some private parameter, for example, void fun_2(){ charString  = "abc"; //charString is a private member of Class}, then for a fun_2, this is not a member function. Is it able to direct access?

Comment: @Ian: `fun_2()` should still be able to access class members because `fun_2()` is still a member function of `MyClass`. `fun_2_wrapper()` is there so that `_beginthread()` can call your thread routine.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to do this is to use a static member function that calls the member function using a void pointer to the original object.

```
class Class
{
public:
   void fun_1(void)
   {
      _beginthread( &Class::static_fun_2, 0, this );
   }
   void fun_2(void)
   {
      printf("hello");
   }
private:
   static void static_fun_2( void * args )
   {
      static_cast<Class*>(args)->fun_2();
   }

};
```

However if you start needing to pass arguments to those functions things get a little more complicated. I'd look at using boost::thread and boost::bind instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Can you use `boost::bind` or `std::bind` directly with `_beginthread` thereby skipping the need for a static function?

Comment: @User I don't think you can use the binds directly since you're passing arguments to `_beginthread` which need to be of a certain function type. However you can create a wrapper for `_beginthread` in the style of `boost::thread` that will accept more general functions - allowing you to use bind.