# Error of argument type with _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, multithreading, arguments, beginthreadex

To define my thread I have in my Header file:

```
class HttpClient
{
public:
    ...
    unsigned int __stdcall  PerformLogin(void*);
    ...

};
```

Then in my cpp file I have:

```
unsigned int __stdcall PerformLogin(void*){
...
}
```

And to call this thread I use

```
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &PerformLogin, NULL, 0, &threadID );
```

But i Have an error on the `&PerformLogin` saying that:

> the args of type unsigned int (__stdcall HttpClient::*)(void*) is not compatible with the param unsigned int (__stdcall*)(void*).

I understand the error, but I really don't know how to fix this!

Comment: You're missing the `HttpClient::` at the beginning of `PerformLogin`'s definition. You'll still get an error after you add it (as @hmjd) describes, though, but at least your class will be defined correctly.

Comment: @darkheir: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259815/beginthreadex-static-member-function for sample code of using `_beginthreadex` with member functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to fix this would be to make the member function `static`, though this means `PerformLogin()` does not have a `this` pointer and would have no access to non-static members of `HttpClient`.

Another is to move `PerformLogin()` out of `HttpClient` altogether, and make it a free function.

Comment: I'm going to try to move PerformLogin() out, seems to be a good solution!

Comment: @darkheir, you should decide where to put your functions based on other criteria, like where does it belong in your model considering OOP principles.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually to is to add 'this' as the void* parameter to the static function - you can then call methods on it in the static function with a bit of casting..

Comment: This is redundant, see my answer

Comment: It's not redundant. Casting to `this` is better than relying on calling convention hackery.

Comment: @tenfour, you're right about hackiness, but I still deem the implicit `this` approach better.

Answer (score 0):

Member functions get `this` pointer implicitly as a first parameter.
So if you want to start a thread with a class member function, you should explicitly pass a pointer to a class instance in your call to `_beginthreadex`.

So, remove explicit argument:

```
class HttpClient
{
    public:
    ...
    unsigned int __stdcall  PerformLogin();
    ...
};
```

And call `_beginthreadex` while passing `this` as an argument:

```
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &PerformLogin, this, 0, &threadID );
```

It's worth mentioning that this is a bit hacky. C++ FAQ [advises against it](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2).
I still prefer this approach. Of course I just use `boost::thread` usually.